# Adding Google Analytics to your Intranet without a fully qualified domain name?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I'd like to run Google Analytics on our farm, but none of our links are fully qualified domains (for example, our main intranet is hosted at `http://sharepoint`). Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Google is not supporting the non-FQDN url:

> **Your company intranet**
>
> In order for Google Analytics to generate reports for your corporate
>   intranet usage, your corporate network must be able to reach the
>   Google Analytics JavaScript file (analytics.js). Try loading the file
>   in your browser using one of the following links:
>
> - http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
> - https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
>
> If you can reach one of these URLs from your internal network, you can
>   use Google Analytics to collect data from your intranet. Your intranet
>   must also be accessible through a fully qualified domain name such as
>   http://intranet.example.com. **The Google Analytics JavaScript won't
>   work if your intranet can only be accessed using a domain name that
>   isn't fully qualified, such as `http://intranet`**

Source: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009688?hl=en

One interesting link to check, may solve the issue:
http://chadschroeder.blogspot.com/2011/01/google-analytics-works-on-your-intranet.html